# sqlite3.OperationalError: near “<”: syntax error

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, discord.py

line 115, in add
self.cursor.execute(f'UPDATE GuildTable SET GUILD_NAME = {str(guild_name_msg)} WHERE GUILD_IDS = {ctx.guild.id}')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

```
self.cursor.execute(f'UPDATE GuildTable SET GUILD_NAME = {str(guild_name_msg)} WHERE GUILD_IDS = {ctx.guild.id}')
```

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "<": syntax error

**What should i do?**

```
        try:                
            guild_name_msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)

            self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT GUILD_NAME FROM GuildTable WHERE GUILD_IDS = {ctx.guild.id}")                
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()
            if result is None:
                self.cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO GuildTable(GUILD_NAME) VALUES({str(guild_name_msg)})')
            elif result is not None:
                self.cursor.execute(f'UPDATE GuildTable SET GUILD_NAME = {str(guild_name_msg)} WHERE GUILD_IDS = {ctx.guild.id}')
                    
            self.db.commit()
            self.cursor.close()
            self.db.close()
```

Comment: try and instead of f string it use dict or tuple

Answer (score 1):

```py
try:
    guild_name_msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)

    self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT GUILD_NAME FROM GuildTable WHERE GUILD_IDS = :guild_id", {"guild_id": ctx.guild.id})
    result = self.cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        self.cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO GuildTable(GUILD_NAME) VALUES (?)',guild_name_msg)
    elif result is not None:
        self.cursor.execute(
            f'UPDATE GuildTable SET GUILD_NAME = :guild_name_msg WHERE GUILD_IDS = :guild_id',{"guild_id":ctx.guild.id,"guild_name_msg":guild_name_msg})

    self.db.commit()
    self.cursor.close()
    self.db.close()
```

I think your error was that the first thing it does is to combine the strings which then doesn't run well in the SQL but if you pass the values in a dict or a tuple it SQLite will understand that it's supposed to use them as values in the DB